# Determine whether the series converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n^2})}{1-\sin(\frac{1}{n})}$$

Using the limit comparison test twice I determined it converges however the process was longer than I thought necessary. I feel like I am overlooking a simpler solution, what other methods would be viable?

Comment: The denominator goes to $1$ and is therefore irrelevant. $\sin(\frac{1}{n^2})\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$, so the series converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *equivalents*;

$\sin\dfrac1{n^2}\sim_\infty\dfrac1{n^2}$, $1-\sin\frac1n\sim_\infty 1$, hence
$$\frac{\sin\frac1{n^2}}{1-\sin\frac1n}\sim_\infty\frac1{n^2},\quad\text{which converges.}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Can you think of a convenient upper bound on $\sin(1/n^2)$?  Similarly, how does $1 - \sin(1/n)$ behave as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 2):

**HINTS:**

Note that we have

$$\sin(1/n^2)\le \frac1{n^2}$$

and for $n>1$

$$\frac{1}{1-\sin(1/n)}\le \frac1{1-1/n}$$